# TypeError: zip argument #1 must support iteration when using lambda function with zip

Tags: python, pandas, lambda, zip

I have some code below that gives me an error message of

> TypeError: zip argument #1 must support iteration.

I believe the error is due to the function:

> get_account_jira_account_name(year_month, outage['tenant'])

returning Empty.

I am wondering how can I return an Empty value that can support iteration?

```
def get_account_jira_account_name(year_month, tenant):
    sql_tenant_account = f'''
    Some query";'''
    df=get_dataframe(sql_tenant_account)

    if not df.empty:
        account_name = df['account_name'].values[0]
        jira_account_name = df['jira_account_name'].values[0]
    else:
        sql_tenant_account = f'''Some Query";
        ;'''
        df=get_dataframe(sql_tenant_account,'sla','COMMONDB')
        if len(df) !=0:
            account_name = df['account_name'].values[0]
            jira_account_name = ''
            return account_name, jira_account_name
        else:
            print('When I get the error it happens here')
            account_name = 'not found'
            jira_account_name = 'not found'
            return account_name, jira_account_name
```

```
outage_df['account_name'], outage_df['jira_account_name'] = zip(*outage_df.apply(lambda outage: get_account_jira_account_name(year_month, outage['tenant']), axis=1))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically speaking, an empty sequence (empty list, empty string, etc.) is "an empty value that supports iteration."

However, you haven't shown enough of your code for us to know if that solution would actually work in your specific situation.

In your function, when the first `if` statement is true, no `return` statement is executed at all*, therefore the function returns a single `None` value by default, which is not iterable.

`*` And this seems strange, because in the first `if` block, the function goes to the effort of assigning values for `account_name` and `jira_account_name`, but then doesn't actually **do** anything with them.  Perhaps you meant to have `return account_name, jira_account_name` in that block also?)

Comment: thank you adding a return statement in the if helped solve the problem.